# Alternative to Plot.ly

Tags: library, python, iot

I currently use plot.ly to plot live sensor sensor so that I can view it from my phone.

I am on the free account and I have a really hard time with reliability. I cant really justify $400 a year for an amateur project, especially as I find it so unreliable.

Can anyone recommend a similar product with:

- Online plotting dashboard
- can upload data with Python
- Stores data online

I don't mind paying if it works.